# why error is occuring while using ocrabbyy addon in g1ant?

Tags: g1ant

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTWh9.png)

This dialog box is getting displayed and I am unable to run the program.

Comment: welcome.. refer How to Ask Question ?

Comment: Ask it in better way, please